# jaxb catch exception if field is not found in java class

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I need to catch the exception when an xml is unmarshalling to a java class if a field and its attribute(s) found in xml file are not defined in java class. I am not able to construct the xsd completely where different xml files dynamically enlarge the xsd, which has different tags in it. That's why in need to catch specified exc,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the service that you are using to parse the xml should throw a TagNotMappedException (for example) so that you can easily catch it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will not throw an exception if an unmapped element/attribute has been encountered unless the default `ValidationEventHandler` has been overridden or an instance of `Schema` has been sent on the `Unmarshaller`.

**Java Model (Root)**

```
package forum15875338;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum15875338;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    private static final String XML = "<root><foo>Hello</foo><bar>World</bar></root>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Unmarshal #1 = Default Unmarshal
        System.out.println("Unmarshal #1");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(XML));
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

        // Unmarshal #2 - Override Default ValidationEventHandler
        System.out.println("Unmarshal #2");
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        });
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(XML));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Unmarshal #1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <foo>Hello</foo>
</root>
Unmarshal #2
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"bar"). Expected elements are <{}foo>
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"bar"). Expected elements are <{}foo>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at forum15875338.Demo.main(Demo.java:31)
```